# Facing application crash after updating Glide Library to V4

Tags: android, image, android-glide

After updating gilde library to v4 android app is crashing with this error message

```
   java.lang.IllegalStateException: You cannot call Glide.get() in registerComponents(), use the provided Glide instance instead
    at com.bumptech.glide.Glide.checkAndInitializeGlide(Glide.java:196)
    at com.bumptech.glide.Glide.get(Glide.java:182)
    at com.bumptech.glide.Glide.getRetriever(Glide.java:749)
    at com.bumptech.glide.Glide.with(Glide.java:776)
```

Please help me solve this issue, After reading glide migration document I have created the class with gilde annotation.

```
@GlideModule public final class MyAppGlideModule extends AppGlideModule {}
```

Crashing does not solve with this.

Comment: https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/2780#issuecomment-553835662

Comment: [http://sjudd.github.io/glide/doc/generatedapi.html](http://sjudd.github.io/glide/doc/generatedapi.html) Created glide options same as mentioned here. This solved crash